# Is there a way in laravel to manually finish the job within handle method?

Tags: laravel, redis

The job automatically accomplishes when it reaches the end of the handle method without any exceptions or intervention.

```
public function handle(){
    if($problem){
        // manage the problem
        return $this->release(5);
    }else{
        // do nothing and the job will finish anyways
    }
}
```

But is there a manually way to finish the job, like

```
public function handle(){
    if($problem){
        return $this->release(5);
    }else{
        return $this->finish();
    }
}
```

Maybe I overlooked it but I couldn't find such a piece of information.

Comment: yes you are doing correct. In PHP, if you add return statement then function will not execute after return statement of function.

Comment: Do you mean I should just use `return` without anything else to (gracefully) accomplish the job?

Comment: yes try this it will work.

Comment: Great.. enjoy buddy.